# MySQL REGEXP_SUBSTR() escaping issue?

Tags: mysql, regex, icu

Please take the following example regex:

https://regexr.com/4ek7r

As you can see, the regex works great and matches the sizes (e.g. 3/16" etc) from the product descriptions.

I'm trying to implement this in MySQL 8.0.15 using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) I have doubled up the escape characters but the regex is not working.

Please see the following SQL fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e6Ez3XCdU5Ahs91z6TQA8P/0

As you can see, `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` returns `NULL`

I'm presuming this is an escape issue - but i'm not 100% sure.

How can I ensure MySQL returns the 1st match per product (row) akin to the regexr.com example?

Cheers

**Edit: 28/05/2019 - root cause**

Wiktor's answer below solved my problem and his regex was much cleaner & well worth the upvote. That said, i didn't understand why my original version was not working after the port from SQL Server to MySQL. I finally noticed the problem this morning - it had nothing to do with the regex, it was a rookie error in string concatenation! Specifically, I was using `UPPER(Description + ' ')` (i.e. using `+`) - which works fine in SQL Server but obviously; MySQL forces numeric! So i was essentially running my regex against a `0`! Replacing the `+` with `CONCAT` actually fixed my original query with original regex - just thought i'd share this in case it helps anyone else!

Comment: You have enables a case insensitive mode at regexr. Add `(?i)` at your pattern start.

Comment: Please share the exact sample input you are trying to match with your regex.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, i've provided the exact sample input in the SQL fiddle, i've also used UPPER() in the MySQL to handle case (regex is in upper case)

Comment: What did you try to match with `(?=[.\s()$])`? I am interested in `$` - end of string or `$`  symbol?

Comment: I don't think MySQL REGEXP_SUBSTR can do `(?=...` (lookaheads).

Comment: @SalmanA MySQL 8.x can

Comment: Hi Wikto, the $ was intended for the end of string yes, that said, I wrote that regex a few years ago & welcome suggestions to improve it - in fact, i append a space to the description in the SQL because the $ doesn't work (The regex has been used in SQL Server for a few years using a custom .net CLR - we're porting to MySQL 8 etc)

Comment: Check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agJtNK6f44AubF2GtkHmxJ/0

Comment: Hi Wiktor, that looks perfect! How on earth? Genuinely Impressed (& Grateful!) - When you pop it as an answer please can you explain what the key problem was? i can see you've changed to non-capturing groups etc - was that the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL v8.x that supports ICU regex, you may use

```
SELECT Description, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Description, '(?im)(?=\\b(?:[0-9/]+(?:\\.[0-9/]+)?\\s*(?:[X-]|$)|[0-9/\\s]+(?:\\.[0-9/]+)?(?:[CM]?M|["”TH])))[0-9/\\s.]+(?:[CM]?M|["”TH])?(?:\\s*[/X-]\\s*[0-9/\\s.]+(?:[CM]?M|["”TH])?)?(?=[.\\s()]|$)') AS Size FROM tbl_Example
```

The main points:

- The flags can be used as inline options,  `(?mi)`, `m` will enable multiline mode when `^` and `$` match start/end of a line and `i` will enable case insensitive mode
- `[$]` matches a `$` char, to match end of a line position, you need to move `$` out of a character class, use alternations in this case (`(?=[\.\s\(\)$])` -> `(?=[.\s()]|$)`, yes, do not escape what does not have to be escaped, too)
- Matching fractional number part, it is better to use a `(?:\.[0-9/]+)?` like pattern (it matches an optional sequence of `.` and then 1 or more digits or `/`s)
- `(C|M)?` is better written as `[CM]?` (a character class is more efficient)